# How to find a generic parabola through 3 arbitrary points in R^2?

Tags: conic-sections

Given $(a,b)$, $(c,d)$, and $(e,f)$ (assume non-collinear and $a\neq c$, $c\neq e$, and $a\neq e$), is there a generic way to find a parabolic function between the three?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes.  Write $y = Ax^2 + Bx + C$.  Substitute in the three points; if the values $a$, $c$ and $e$ are distinct, you get a nondegenerate system of three linear equations in three unknowns.  Solve for $A$, $B$ and $C$ and you are there.

Comment: The assumption here, of course, is that the parabola sought has an axis parallel to a coordinate axis. A parabola in general position, however, is only completely determined by **four** points.

Comment: Correct.  He seeks a quadratic.  This gives one, but it has a graph so that $y$ is a function of $x$.

Comment: Otherwise the problem is underdetermined.