# Parabola - equation from three points

Tags: algebra-precalculus, conic-sections

Question:
Find the equation of the parabola whose axis is parallel to the y-axis and which passes through the points (0,4) (1,9) and (-2,6)

Well as the parabola has its axis parallel to the y-axis and it is obviously opening upwards, the general form can be written as:
$$(x-h)^2 = 4a(y-k)$$

Then I would have to go through the painstaking task of solving three variables from three equations. Obvious method to do it. I was wondering if there's any easier way of doing it?

Comment: Related question: http://math.stackexchange.com/q/889569/3301

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to find a generic parabola through 3 arbitrary points in R^2?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/104449/how-to-find-a-generic-parabola-through-3-arbitrary-points-in-r2)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general formula for a parabola is $f(x)=ax^2+bx+c$.

- Plugging in $(0,4)$, we get: $c=4$.
- Plugging in $(1,9)$, we get: $a+b+c=9$.
- Plugging in $(-2,6)$, we get: $4a-2b+c=6$.

The system of equations to be solved becomes:

$\begin{cases}a+b=5 \\ 4a-2b=2 \end{cases}$

This gives $a=2$ and $b=3$.

The formula for your parabola becomes: $f(x)=2x^2+3x+4$.

Comment: I see. But any easier way to do it?

Comment: Even easier? No, I don't think so.

Comment: What is easier than posting on [Mathematics.SE] and having someone else solve it for you?

Comment: @ja72 The point isn't to get the answer. Rather to get a method to use in future problems.........

Comment: 48 seconds left lol